# How to send an e‑mail to an address with Latin9/iso‑8859‑15 characters inside the username part of the address?

Tags: email, encoding, character-encoding

As part of finding a job, I need to send an e‑mail to an address which contains latin letters with accents inside the username.

I know this is not standard, but they did it and there’s less than [1000 of the required job for all the country](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/137890). I can’t afford not to write to them.

So they did something wrong on their servers in order to get a situation like this working anyway if the e‑mail address is encoded correctly (perhaps this is a hidden challenge as this is for a computing job).

How to send an e‑mail to such address given most clients refuses to send or replace characters by a `?` and many SMTP servers don’t relay it ? Their target ꜱᴍᴛᴘ server doesn’t signal support of `SMTPUTF8`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844431/are-email-addresses-allowed-to-contain-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: @Worthwelle no they don’t explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Send the email-address in UTF8 anyway, even if the server doesn't advertise it.
For the user-part of an email address UTF8 should be allowed and relays should normally forward this as any other mail.
It might be really problematic to get your own ISP mail-relay to accept such emails.
If all else fails simple register a free GMail or Outlook account and send the email via their web-service. Both services should support this.

It remains a real stupid thing to do by any company, unless it is intended as a challenge as you already mentioned. Even then is a dumb thing as many mail-services can't handle UTF8 properly, which causes a lot of extra complications for your respondents.

Comment: No the character encoding expected is likely latin9 or latin1 which is used for such cases there. **Gmail and outlook support ꜱᴍᴛᴘᴜᴛꜰ8 only if the target server says so** otherwise, they refuse to send the e-mail. So even then I don’t know any way to send it which is the real point of the question, not if it’s possible.

Comment: That would mean their mail-system is totally incompatible with the rest of the internet. There is NO WAY you can send any mail to them in that case, unless you handcode the mailmessage yourself. Make a telnet connection to their SMTP server and manualy copy/paste the message directly in their server.

Comment: Or just that an alternative encoding needs to be used which isn’t Unicode (when we don’t use Unicode there we use latin9 so the right encoding isn’t difficult to get). I need a client supporting ꜱ/ᴍɪᴍᴇ encryption which doesn’t modify the e‑mail address, I mean to treat the address as if it was a binary.